# How to create music on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, music

I'd like to start creating music on Linux.

From 8 bit music, through creating instruments (for my synthesizer) to DJ mixing. What are first steps I should do if I got my computer only and synthesizer?

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution readymade for you, it's called …

### Ubuntu Studio

[Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/) is a branch of Ubuntu that comes prepackaged with software for audio recording, graphics production and video editing. You can find [the official Wiki here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuStudio).

Here is the page for the [audio packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/Audio).

#### Ardour

What's most interesting for you is probably [Ardour](http://ardour.org/):

> Ardour is a DAW (Digital Audio Workstation) application for advanced audio editing. Ardour's capabilities include: multichannel recording, non-destructive editing with unlimited undo/redo, full automation support, a powerful mixer, unlimited tracks/busses/plugins, timecode synchronization, anything to anywhere signal routing, support for standard audio file formats (BWF, WAV, WAV64, AIFF, CAF & more), video synchronisation with SMPTE or MTC code via JACK, support for steinberg's VST plugins as well as linux LADSPA, LV2 plugin standards and hardware control from surfaces like the Mackie Control Universal.

[image]

#### Mixxx

Here's your solution for DJing: [Mixxx](http://www.mixxx.org/).

> Mixxx is a virtual DJ console that supports most popular digital audio formats, including mp3, ogg, and wave. It has the ability to estimate the BPM of tracks, time stretch independently from pitch shifting, control playback via timecoded vinyl (Serato, Traktor, etc..), and use hardware controllers (Tascam US-428, Hercules DJ Console, etc...).

[image]

#### QSynth

[QSynth](http://qsynth.sourceforge.net/qsynth-index.html) is a software synthesizer GUI for [FluidSynth](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/fluidsynth/), which allows you to create SoundFont-based synthesizers.

[image]

---

If you have an external synthesizer with MIDI ports, you will somehow need to get the MIDI signal to your computer and back. If you don't have one yet, you might consider getting an external audio interface. Not all support Linux, but some of them do. Here's [a website that lists some](http://linuxstudiopro.com/). [4Front](http://www.opensound.com/) offers third-party drivers for M-Audio hardware, I read.